# Flutter: Firestore security rule VS if condition in dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

if my app already restricted data display to registered user at UI level, something like below in dart:

```
    if (user == "is_valid") {
      display the stuff...
    }
```

Do i still need to setup security rule in my console ?

```
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

one more thing is if my code does not query certain collections, say the name is "draft" or "trash" just storing some unused data, should i still setup rules to block access to those collections? Or they are safe enough as my code will never query them ?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to consider that your app's code isn't guaranteed to run the way you want once it gets installed on a device that you don't fully control.  Also, there is nothing stopping someone from reverse engineering your app's code in order to figure out how to query your database directly without needing your app at all.  If you want to prevent these problems, then you should use security rules to enforce permissions that you require.

Comment: if i want to restrict access to certain document based on "document id", is it possible in security rule ?

Comment: Sorry, your requirement is kind of vague.  I think you should review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to find out how security rules work, then ask a new question if you're stuck implementing a specific kind of rule.